# What would cause HTTP to send back "400 OK"

Tags: jquery, http, air, http-headers

I'm receiving an error sometimes for what should be a valid request as "400 OK" when I PUT some arguments to a URL.

The same URL and arguments will work 99% of the time, but I'm seeing errors crop up in our logs.

Is that an obscure thing that can happen due to some factors or is something specific to my app causing the mish-mash of strange headers? I'm guessing it's the latter if there's no answers to the former :)

**UPDATE**

For the comments, "it" is a relatively simple RESTful API that was written. Now it's almost always giving back the right headers like 400 and body of error or 200 with body of ok. When a bad header makes it to the web client, the web client is pinging a reporting URL with the message it got so we can differentiate API errors between our web app and mobile apps. As far as we know there is no combintation of code that would make this "400 OK" hell. But seeing as it seems impossible for that to happen outside of our code messing up, I'm going to take a deeper look.

**UPDATE 2**

Okay I've delved deeper into our framework than I have in a long time and spoke with some devs.

It returns the information via the AJAX call to the API to the browser.

The browser detects a "400 OK" and sends it back to our server, where we are getting this strange report. No one has seen this happen with their eyes, but the logs say it's happening.

There is literally zero code in our codebase that would return 400 OK since the only 400 in our HTTP header handlers are "400 bad request"

I'm wondering now if there's some browser/jquery/ajax bug I've stumbled into.

**UPDATE 3 (because you can't have too much information)**

I checked how the browser sees what's wrong. A callback is fired on failure as reported by jQuery $.ajax. We then have code like this:

```
xhr.always(function() {
  var request = [ this.type, this.url, this.data ].join(' '),
      response = [ xhr.status, xhr.statusText, xhr.responseText ].join(' ');

  $.ajax({ 
    url   : REPORTING_URL,
    type  : 'POST', 
    data : { request : request, response : response }
  });
});
```

And we know this works "most" of the time because we also received "400 error" responses from these ajax calls

**UPDATE 4**

I just noticed that literally all the errors came from user agent:

`Mozilla webkit etc...... AdobeAIR/1.5.3` which is a very old version

Our AIR app just has an iframe of our web app. I can only imagine what's happening there.

Comment: It can't send back "400 OK". That's not an HTTP status code. It can send back "400" (Bad Request). What treats it as "OK"? Perhaps showing the *real* response headers would be insightful ..

Comment: Of course it can send back "400 OK". "It" can send whatever "it" likes. He didn't even say what "it" is! Maybe he implemented "it" himself.

Comment: @pst Why that ? You can send any header you want if you implement it.

Comment: Based on comments it seems one of the devs on this app is making "it" send back the wrong thing because as you guys say, and I thought, that regular old HTTP can NOT ever send back something like that

Comment: I suggest that _first_ Dave Stein says what "it" is, _then_ we can proceed to the next step.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like someone left a bug in the implementation of the API.

Comment: Yeah digging into it now to see

Comment: "The browser detects a "400 OK" and sends it back to our server.."? This is inside an AJAX handler? Can test the browser bug, by seeing if it comes from different browsers (e.g. if it's only one UA or many different ones) .. I'd *imagine* the jQuery code uses the status-code (exclusively?), but I haven't looked at it in detail.

Comment: Okay looked at more code and about to make update 3

Comment: `always` doesn't look like `fail` .. if jQuery was really raising a "fail" (and not a `done`) then I'd say it was a bug with jQuery. I suspect it's not *really* a "fail" in jQuery, but it looks like it (because of a confusing Reason-Phrase) .. but that still doesn't explain how it gets in to start with. Is there a way to monitor this locally/in-action (e.g. with Fiddler2 or Firebug)?

Comment: Well no one has been able to replicate it in the app, even though we know which request is failing. I am currently messing around with headers in FF, Chrome, and IE to find some weird combination that might make it "confused" do 400 OK. Like I said, there is no place in our code that has 400 without the words "Bad Request" ( aside from like random hexes in libraries like PHPExcel )

Comment: @DaveStein That *should* be parsed from the HTTP status line itself in the XHR implementation (which is then used by jQuery) .. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @pst's great answer which I marked as the official answer, I found a more depressing answer that was 100% true for my case.

This header was coming via using a website in an iframe for users of Adobe AIR 1.5.3.

After force-upgrading all of our AIR users it went away so it's safe to assume this was a bug of their header reporting.

Comment: Thanks for posting the issue: glad the problem is "resolved" :) Is it a bug/issue specifically wrt AIR 1.5.3 then?

Comment: It would seem that ways since there haven't been anymore 400 OKs reported to my server since the forced upgrade a week ago. So if anyone runs into this in the future they just need to do the same to their users. It's a bit trickier to force update since the AIR marketplace has been discontinued.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was wrong in my comments above, as per the RFC 2616 the [Status Line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) is of the format:

```
Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
```

The RFC goes on to say:

> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request. These codes are fully defined in section 10. The Reason-Phrase is intended to give a short textual description of the Status-Code. **The Status-Code is intended for use by automata** and **the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user.** The client is not required to examine or display the Reason- Phrase.

So a server *could* return "1.1 400 OK". But this would hardly be a well-chosen Reason-Phrase. It would be much better to stick with the reasons listed with the status codes to avoid such confusion. (And perhaps avoid issues with [overly] picky clients/proxies.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just posted a second update to maybe shed some more light

Comment: Gonna mark this as answer for now and look to see if I can find the actual cause in code somewhere - I've searched for all instances of 400 btw, not just in the http header handler we use.

Comment: In the next day or two we'll be able to boot off all the users using the old version of AIR ( as all errors are still coming frmo that exact client ) So if the errors go away with that I'll have to answer my own question and say what the hell did that. But I'll still keep the upvote on you :D Just wanted to keep you in loop since yo had good answer